# How do I change the Apache root permission?

Tags: apache, permissions, root

Upgrade to PHP 7.1 and getting 403 error. How do I change the  root permission to 751?

Answer (score 0):

As the root user, run:

```
chmod 751 path/to/your/directory/
```

use the "recursive" option if you want to also modify permissions of all subdirectories:

```
chmod -R 751 path/to/your/directory/
```

then do this:

```
ls -l
```

This should show that your directory is owned by root and now has permissions "drwxr-x--x".

Source and more details: http://www.filepermissions.com/directory-permission/751